# How to not restart the server everytime when working with Flask or Express?

Tags: zend-framework, node.js, flask

I am new on web app development.

My question is ...
I have tried some hand-on development on Zend + Apache(php) , Flask(python), Express under node.js.

I found that when I start doing development on
Zend framework + Apache, there is no need to restart the apache every time when there is code change in PHP under Controller, Model or Views. It is very convenient and fast!

However, if I work on Flask or Express, I have to restart the whole application everytime when i change code on Controller or Model part. There is no need to restart the server if there is code change on View parts. However, it is annoying enough!!!

Right now, i am working on the project on Flask, how can I avoid the restart the server everytime??? Can the problem be solved if i put the whole web app on top of Nginx??

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 7):

UPDATE:

When debug mode is on for Flask, the server will detect for changes::

```
from application import app
app.debug = True

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

However, in production setting, it is not recommended to auto-refresh the server.

---

Run it on top of `tornado`:

```
$ pip install tornado
```

Create a new file `server.py`, which wrap up the `app.py`:

```
from tornado import autoreload
from tornado.wsgi import WSGIContainer
from tornado.httpserver import HTTPServer
from tornado.ioloop import IOLoop

http_server = HTTPServer(WSGIContainer(app))
http_server.listen(5000)
ioloop = IOLoop.instance()
autoreload.start(ioloop)
ioloop.start()
```

Comment: Why it works? Are they tracking the io different and auto reload the server?

Comment: For apache+ php, does the apache reload implicitly??

Answer (score 2):

If running with mod_wsgi, you just need to change or *touch* the WSGI script that `WSGIScriptAlias` points to.

```
touch /home/user/env/app.wsgi
```

See http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ReloadingSourceCode

Answer (score 0):

If you run with the [debugger](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.6.11/api/debugger.html) on, you can use the [restart command](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.6.11/api/debugger.html#execution_control) to restart the script without restarting the entire server.